# IOS Customkeyboard get nil value in nsuserdefault

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, custom-keyboard

I am working on custom keyboard with appextension. it is based on onehandhand keyboard. when user need to access with right hand it needs to select right hand and if user need to type with left hand user can select left side keyboard. I have set value in Nsuserdefault for the key layout.
here is my try.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {//group.keyboaredExtention
_defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.project"];
[_defaultvalue setBool:YES forKey:@"Layout"];
[_defaultvalue synchronize];

 //This is my viewcontroller which contain code for setting left and right keyboard.
 - (IBAction)RightAction:(id)sender {
_defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.project"];
[_defaultvalue setBool:YES forKey:@"Layout"];
[_defaultvalue synchronize]; 
[_rightView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:63.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[_leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [_rightView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[_leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0 blue:196.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

}

- (IBAction)leftAction:(id)sender {
 _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.project"];
[_defaultvalue setBool:NO forKey:@"Layout"];
[_defaultvalue synchronize];

[_rightView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[_leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0 blue:196.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

}
```

and here is my keyboard viewcontroller.m file .

```
      -(void)LoadKeyboardview
    {


if(isPortrait)
{
    _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.project"];

    NSLog(@"==%@",@"asdfasf");
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"Layout"] == NO)
     {
        NSLog(@"True");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"False");
    }

    if([_defaultvalue boolForKey:@"Layout"] == YES)
    {
        self.ObjKeyLayout=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"keyboardLayout" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addGesturToKeyBoard];
        self.view =self.ObjKeyLayout;
        [self updateCustomHeight];

    }
    else{


        self.ObjKeyLayout=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"leftLayout" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addGesturToKeyBoard];




        self.view =self.ObjKeyLayout;
        [self updateCustomHeight];

    }


}
else
{


    self.ObjKeyLayout=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"LandscapLayout" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addGesturToKeyBoard];
     //[self.ObjKeyLayout setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    self.inputView =self.ObjKeyLayout;
    [self updateCustomHeight];

}
}
```

Note:- I am getting value for nsuserdefault in viewcontroller.m file for left keyaboard "0" and for Right keyboard "1". But not able to get value in Keyboardviewcontroller.m file. **Po[_defaultuder boolforkey:@"Layout"]** shows me value Nil.

So, How can i get value in Keyboardlayout.m file ?